# Normalize data in feature engineering

Tags: list-manipulation, machine-learning

Here is the dataset to be used to train the model.

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 10}]; (*100 samples with 10 features each*)

(*Normalize each feature to be standard gaussian N(0,1)*)

μ = Mean[data]
σ = StandardDeviation[data]

normaldata = ((# - μ)/σ) & /@ data;
(*Plot one the first feature, but the plot does not look like normal distribution!*)

ListPlot[normaldata[[1]], Joined -> True]
```

What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Additions and multiplications to Uniformly distributed data result in .... Uniformly distributed data

Comment: Shouldn't the values for the first *feature* correspond to `normaldata[[All, 1]]`? Also, if you want to generate normally distributed multivariate data, you should look into `MultinormalDistribution`: `RandomReal` generates *uniformly distributed* data, as Belisarius mentioned.

Comment: The plot *does* look like points taken from a normal distribution, with mean $0$ and and $\sigma = 1$.  What were you expecting?

Comment: Try:  `Graphics[{Point[{#, 0}] & /@ normaldata[[1]],
  {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{\[Mu][[1]], 0}]}}]`.

Answer (score 5):

Way back in the days when I was programming 8-bit microprocessors in assembly language and I had to keep things down to simple arithmetic, I generated pretty good approximations to normal variates with code that translates into *Mathematica* as follows:

#### Tools

```
 normalVariate[μ_, σ_] := Total[RandomReal[{μ - 4 σ, μ + 4 σ}, 5]]/5
 stats[sample_] := Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}[sample]]
```

#### Application

```
SeedRandom[1];
sample = Table[normalVariate[0, 1], 1000];
stats[sample]
```

> `{0.052734, 1.03348}`

```
Histogram[sample]
```

[image: histo1]

This divides the full sample up in 100 sub-samples with ten value in each.

```
data = Partition[sample, 10];
```

Perhaps you might use this approach to generate your training sets.

Comment: +1 Which micros? We want details!

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. Started with 8080, then 8085, Z80, and 8088,

Comment: Ha! when men were men machines weren't a New Kind of anything :). I miss the 6502's too :)

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. The 6502 is one I never programmed. I worked in an Intel-oriented shop. The Z80 was in my home computer, a S100 bus thing that I built with my very own soldering iron and screw-driver. A very advanced machine with two 256-Kbyte floppy drives (yes, two!) and 24 Kbytes of ram. I was the envy of all my fellow nerds. I had a VT100 terminal attached to it. (This was in 1978 -- the 8080 was in '74)

Comment: +1 The man can be recreated as a programmer!